# type TreeSet does not take parameters?

Tags: java, generics, treeset

```
package treeset;

import java.util.*;
public class TreeSet {
public static void main(String[] args) {       
SortedSet<String> herbSetOrder = new TreeSet<String>(herbSet); 
System.out.println("First herb is: " + herbSetOrder.first()); 
System.out.println("Last herb is: " + herbSetOrder.last()); 
    }   
}
```

I want to print the first and last element in the Set 
but it give me an error say "TreeSet does not take parameters"?

Comment: Please show the exact error you have, since `TreeSet` has a constructor that accepts a `Collection`.

Comment: What you want is to create a `new java.util.TreeSet(herbSet)`.

Comment: 'SortedSet<String> herbSetOrder = new TreeSet<String>(herbSet);'

Comment: Not usually a good idea to give your class the same name as the API class that you're using inside it.  Your problem here is that the compiler thinks you want your _own_ class, at `new TreeSet<String>`, and is complaining that _your_ class is not a generic, unlike `java.util.TreeSet`.

Answer (score 3):

You have your own `TreeSet` class, so it is used instead of `java.util.TreeSet`. Rename your class and it'd be fine.

Comment: I rename it stil there is part of error say "it can't find symbol : varible herbSet"

Comment: That's because you never defined `herbSet` anywhere in your code, or if you did, you didn't post that part. The compiler means exactly what it says.